# What is the idiomatic way to express "The man is supporting himself by placing his palm against the wall"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idioms

Look at this picture

[image]

"**The man is standing and supporting himself by placing his palm against the wall**"

Do we say "**He is standing with his palm against the wall**"? or **is there any idiomatic way to say it?**

Comment: Just *He's **leaning*** (or ***propped up***) ***against** the wall*. English doesn't have any particularly common way of distinguishing the way the boy is supporting himself (using his hand) from the girl (leaning with her ***back*** against the wall).

Comment: Unsure how you would describe that strong body language: he has her half trapped, she has a defensive/submissive posture.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica, is it okay to say "The man is leaning on his palm against the wall." or "Tha man is leaning with his palm against the wall"?

Comment: Yeah, they're both fine. I'd slightly prefer ***with*** over ***on*** - but that's just a personal choice, no real significance.